# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { when loading jQueryUImin file

Tags: jquery, user-interface, console

My code is very simple html and attaching jQuery, jQueryUI javascript files, and the ui.css and the code is as follows

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <link href="ui_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-220min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1114uimin.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btn").button();
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="btn">Click</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I am getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" in the browser console while I render the page. Actually this error arises sometimes usually when I clear the cache/history of the browser; And I found WHY this comes!!. This error occurs due to the jQueryUI is not loading completely, loading only partially. Sometimes the jQueryUImin javascript is loading completely and sometimes partially. This is the reason I am getting this error.

I need a solution for this and I dont know why this happens. Any have similar situation

Answer (score 0):

Try to include all js and css files from [cdn](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btn").button();
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="btn">Click</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Of course it will work.  I tried it already. But why it is not working in localhost or our server?

Comment: Not sure why, but google cdn will always keep those files on their server, so nothing wrong to use them. Though its an alternative to avoid issues.